# Material UI: Can I use React component in the DataGrid cell instead of predefined cell types ('string', 'number', 'date', 'dateTime')?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

React, Material UI, TypeScript
I want to put React component into the [DataGrid](https://material-ui.com/ru/components/data-grid) cell. I read about cell custom types [here](https://material-ui.com/ru/components/data-grid/columns/#custom-column-types) but it didn't help me: it allows to manage by string format only, but I need to use component instead of string. For example I want to use [Link](https://material-ui.com/components/links/) component in the cell. My code:

```
{ field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', width: 200,
    valueGetter: (params: ValueGetterParams): JSX.Element =>
        (<Link href={this.props.createRecordUrl(params.row.logicalName as EntityNames,
            params.row.id as ID)} target="_blank">{params.row.name}</Link>)
},
```

But I get the `[object Object]` string instead of `Link` component in the cell. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like using components in columns is only part of the [paid XGrid feature](https://codesandbox.io/s/48hop)? I've used [material-table](https://material-table.com/) in the past, which does allow using [custom components for columns](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/custom-column-rendering).

Comment: Thank you! I will try to use material-table instead of DataGrid.

Comment: The docs are ok but last I checked they're a bit outdated or incomplete. I've had a lot of luck searching github issues (open and closed) to see different approaches to using material-table.

Answer (score 14):

You can insert custom components using the `renderCell` property, which you define in the columns. Have a look at this link for more information: https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/columns/

Example taken from Material UI Docs:

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  {
    field: 'date',
    headerName: 'Year',
    renderCell: (params: GridCellParams) => (
      <strong>
        {(params.value as Date).getFullYear()}
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          size="small"
          style={{ marginLeft: 16 }}
        >
          Open
        </Button>
      </strong>
    ),
  },
];
```

Comment: Wow, this worked perfectly!

The guy above who said it's a paid XGrid feature, is incorrect (at this time at least)

This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: What a pity `GridCellParams` is not generic.